# How to overwrite existing files with ncftpget?

Tags: ncftp

When getting a remote ftp file that exists in the local destination
`ncftpget` says that 
`local file appears to be the same as the remote file, download is not necessary.`

What does `appears` mean? How does `ncftpget` check if this is the same file?

It seems that it compares time and size of the file. But does it compare content or at least checksum?

Is there a way to force to overwrite the existing file. Of course other than remove it first.